# My program is not reading in all of the .txt file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a .txt file into an object and then store it in a linked list but it only will read in half of the file.

[image]

This is what I'm calling to try and read it in but it only reads up to Dodge Demon.

```
 while (CarsFile >> make >> model >> price >> year >> horsePower >> torque >> zeroToSixty >> weight >> quarterMile)
{

    car.setMake(make);
    car.setModel(model);
    car.setPrice(price);
    car.setYear(year);
    car.setHorsePower(horsePower);
    car.setTorque(torque);
    car.setZeroToSixty(zeroToSixty);
    car.setWeight(weight);
    car.setQuarterMile(quarterMile);

    list.appendNode(car);

}
```

Comment: I misread the file. No spaces in names, but commas in the numbers are a problem.

Comment: I changed all the numbers with commas to ints but I'm still having problems

Comment: Here's a working [demo](https://ideone.com/S94MHq) parsing the first 4 lines. (In the future, post the file as text not image so we can test). If you still have issues, try to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The commas in the numbers will make it unable to parse. You could read the file line-by-line, filter out the commas, and use `std::stringstream` to parse.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(CarsFile, line)) {
    // Remove commas
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ','), line.end());
    // Use stringstream to parse
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    if (ss >> make >> model >> price >> year >> horsePower >> torque >> zeroToSixty >> weight >> quarterMile) {
        // Add to list....
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the first comma is used to separate the *make* from the remaining numbers.  By removing the commas, the *make* becomes more difficult to parse, especially when the *make* contains spaces.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't see that. I only see commas in the integers. Ex: line 1, "288,845" should be "288845".

Comment: For example "Ferrari LaFarrari 1,".  In your method the 1 would be considered as the price.  I don't see a global method for all columns; each column or field should be extracted separately.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Possibly, but I see that as make: Ferrari, model: LaFerrari, price: 1,420,112

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `std::getline` to read the text line, then `std::istringstream` to parse the text:

```
std::string  record;
while (std::getline(CarsFile, record))
{
    std::istringstream car_stream(record);
    std::string make;
    std::getline(car_stream, make, ',');
    //...
}
```